# What should happen if I ask Proxy / VPN provider about their service illegal use against me?

Tags: privacy, hacking

Let's say I am running a website that somebody is trying to hack, from the logs I got that he is using mostly VPN servers of X company.

So, even if the VPN company adverts themselves for being 100% anonymous (so-called no-logs policy), how will they cooperate if I could prove that their service is used by someone in an illegal way and it hurts me directly?

Comment: Just because the VPN company doesn't store logs, doesn't mean that some other site they visit (like yours) doesn't store them. They may not have any way to correlate your data with one particular user. Either way I don't think this is the appropriate place for this type of question.

Comment: For any answer to be helpful, jurisdictions of all involved will be needed.  Yours and the VPN companies.

Answer (score 1):

The VPN company does not owe you cooperation but you could compel them by either or both:

1. Reporting the crime to the police (unauthorised access to computer system or similar, depending on the jurisdiction) which may, upon obtaining search warrant, search/seize the VPN company's servers for investigation;
2. Applying for a court order to get the VPN company cooperate. You would need to convince the court that you are suffering damages caused/facilitated by the VPN company.